# MySQL concat() and lower() weirdness

Tags: mysql

Any idea why this works sensibly*:

```
mysql> select lower('AB100c');
+-----------------+
| lower('AB100c') |
+-----------------+
| ab100c          |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But this doesn't?

```
mysql> select lower(concat('A', 'B', 100,'C'));
+----------------------------------+
| lower(concat('A', 'B', 100,'C')) |
+----------------------------------+
| AB100C                           |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*sensibly = 'the way I think it should work.'

Comment: Amazing question!  I just got nailed with this and was able to resolve my problem in about 30 seconds with this thread.  Thanks @shanusmagnus.  (I agree with your sensibly btw...  I can't think of a reason why a string would need to hold '\0' just because it's representing a number.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated on [MySql String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

---

> **LOWER(str)**
>
> LOWER() is ineffective when applied to
>   binary strings (BINARY, VARBINARY,
>   BLOB).

---

> **CONCAT(str1,str2,...)**
>
> Returns the string that results from
>   concatenating the arguments. May have
>   one or more arguments. If all
>   arguments are nonbinary strings, the
>   result is a nonbinary string. If the
>   arguments include any binary strings,
>   the result is a binary string. **A**
>    **numeric argument is converted to its**
>    **equivalent binary string form; if you**
>    **want to avoid that, you can use an**
>    **explicit type cast.**

---

In your code you are passing 100 as a numeric so concat will return a binary string and lower is ineffective when applied to binary strings that's why it's not get converted. If you want to convert you can try this:

```
select lower(concat('A', 'B', '100','C'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer -- I had looked in the document you reference, but failed to grasp the part about how a numeric argument turned the whole string binary.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks. I think this happens in older versions. I had issue in 5.1.73. But not in 5.5.25a.
This was my query(part of query)

COALESCE(NULLIF(lower(name), ''), lower(concat('Agent - ', agent_id)))

I have changed it to 
COALESCE(NULLIF(lower(name), ''), lower(concat('Agent - ', 'agent_id')))

Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

lower is used to convert STRINGS to lowercase. But your value 100 is considered numeric. If you want to still achieve the result of lower case conversion, you should enclose the number in quotes like this:

```
select lower(concat('A', 'B', '100','C'));
```

I've tested this and it works fine.

Comment: Ideally, the coder will build the concat string in a language like PHP. And if this were to be dynamically generated (using a loop, for example), each value to concatenate will be 'quoted'. So I guess the 'looseness' of the concat function is not a real issue.

Answer (score -1):

And here is an other example with CONCAT and LIKE

```
LOWER(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) LIKE LOWER('%my name%')
```